# HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect with spring

Tags: java, spring

I got this HTTP status 400 when I tried to submit "Add form", I also searched this problem and most of the solutions was considered with controller and @RequestParameter.

Here is the form:

```
<form:form commandName="blog" id="newBlog" method="POST"
        cssClass="form-horizontal" action="account">

        <table class="k-widge">

            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td><form:input path="name" cssClass="k-textbox"
                        style="margin-top:3px; margin-bottom: 5px;" name="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Url:</th>
                <td><form:input path="url" cssClass="k-textbox"
                        style="margin-bottom: 5px;" name="url"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save" Class="k-button" id="saveBlog"
                    style="margin-bottom: 5px;"/></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </form:form>
```

and The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doAddBlog(@ModelAttribute("blog") Blog blog,Principal principal){
    String name = principal.getName();
    blogService.save(blog,name);
    return "redirect:/account.html";
}
```

Comment: HTTP Status 400 means your request sent to the server is malformed. What kind of request are you posting to server? If its JSON check if the JSON is valid.

Comment: thanks for replay sir, no it is not JSON

Comment: I see how the _blog_ is mapped by Spring, but how is handled the _principal_ ? Can you share the code were you actually perform the request ?

Comment: the principal is interface built-in in java.security, the container will inject it directly and contains the name of the user that you logged in with and stored in the session.

Answer (score 1):

finally, I solved the problem.
The problem was that when I submitted the form, the action of the form which in this form "account" is appended to the current URL:

the current url "localhost:8080/myapp/users"

and when I submitted the form will appear like this

"localhost:8080/myapp/users/account"

and this "/users/account" is not exist in the request mapping in the controller class.

So, what I did is adding the "/myapp/account" instead of "account" in the form action.

Thanks.